# Django Datetime Issue

Tags: python, django, datetime

What I am trying isn't difficult, however it really isn't working. I cannot see where an error is. In my abstract user model I have an is_donator method that just does not work.

```
    @property 
def is_donator(self):
    if(self.donator >= datetime.now()):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Some reason it just does not return anything, it all looks alright to me though, any ideas?

Comment: And how do you call it? Are you sure that `self.donator` is a datetime object?

Comment: I am calling it from the template & this is my donator declaration: donator = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

Comment: Won't that `>=` always fail as, presumably, they became a donor in the past?

Comment: It sets donator to a date in the future, a month for example

Answer (score 0):

You have two related issues. The first is you are using the wrong comparison.

```
if(self.donator >= datetime.now()):
```

This means that the donor must become a donor at some point in the future.

Change it to

```
if(self.donator <= datetime.now()):
```

This will ensure they became a donor in the past.

The other issue you have is that you are using [auto_now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now):

> Automatically set the field to now **every time the object is saved**.
>   Useful for “last-modified” timestamps. Note that the current date is
>   always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override.

This, then, relates to your first issue. Every time the user field is updated - if you don't explicitly set your field - it defaults to now.

*Update based on comments*: This is checking if your donator is not null and also ensure that it exists. If it doesn't exist, it is up to you to determine your logic, though if it doesn't exist, your user isn't a donator. You can probably just `return False` in your `except` block. This block is pretty verbose, but it shows you explicitly what is happening.

```
def is_donator(self):
    try:
        if self.donator:      # This is checking that self.donator is not null
            if(self.donator >= datetime.now()):
                return True
            else:
                return False  
        else:
            # return false?   # This runs if self.donator is null
    except NameError:
        # do something (or just 'pass', because your self.donator value doesn't exist)
```

Comment: Shall I remove auto_now and changed to auto_add? I just don't want a not null error. Also the donator date is supposed to be in the future, the date is the date up to when they are a donator. I've tried removing the auto_now and it did not work either

Comment: Well it would just be a date in the past, it's the simplest way I can think of having them be a donator for a month

Comment: @CallumBonnyman, that seems misleading to you for when you inevitably need to know a.) When someone stopped being a donor or b.) know who has never been a donor. What 'not null' error where you receiving? There are pythonic ways to handle if a variable is defined or not null

Comment: How would you suggest I do it then?

Comment: I have added that and it just didn't return anything even if i add return false to every other case. It does return something when I take out the if else section that does the date time condition so i'm guessing it's that